# How can I write unit test for creating unique ID?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

This is what I have so far. But I have no idea write tests for making sure it works right.

```
const uniqid = require('uniqid');

module.exports = ({ name }) => {
  return context => {
    // Generate a uniqid and add it user
    context.data['id'] = uniqid(name).toUpperCase();
    return context;
  };
};
```

I am using eslint and mocha

Comment: why does that have `async` ???

Comment: Sorry I will remove it

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to test that `context` receives the appropriate `id`, which is an uppercase `String` beginning with `name` and followed by 18 characters `A-Z` or digits.

I don't know what testing framework you're using, but you could validate `id` with a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

```js
// ignore this, just require the 'uniqid' module
const uniqid = str => `${str}4n5pxq24kpiob12og9`;

const addId = ({name}) => {
  return context => {
    // Generate a uniqid and add it user
    context.data['id'] = uniqid(name).toUpperCase();
    return context;
  };
};

// addId should add an appropriate id to `user.data.id`
const {data: {id}} = addId({name: 'Annie'})({data: {}});
console.assert(/^ANNIE[A-Z\d]{18}$/.test(id));
```

Edit: Since you're using `mocha`, you could also add in `chai` and use its [`match`](https://www.chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_match) method as follows:

```
const {expect} = require('chai');

describe('addId', () => {
  it('should add an appropriate id to `user.data.id`', () => {
    const user = {data: {}};
    addId({name: 'Annie'})(user);
    expect(user.data.id).to.match(/^ANNIE[A-Z\d]{18}$/);
  });
});
```

Comment: I am using eslint and mocha. Sorry forgot the framework.

Comment: @MinhQuangNgo Updated. Let me know if that works as I didn't actually run it. :)

Comment: Oh that's because I named your function that; yours is being exported as `module.exports = ...` so the function is whatever you imported it as; e.g., `const someFn = require('../someFileName');`.